# php running many loops function to scrape data from server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have php script to scrape website based on url input within loop function. here is my script:

```
foreach ($kwArr as $line) {//<- url input
$fetchStat = fetch($line);// function to scrape website
}
```

right now it can scrape 100-200 url, but when i add more than 200 url its timeout.

inside fetch function is using php Simple Dom library.

any idea how can i make it scrape 500+ url without timeout? and without change php.ini timeout parameter?

Comment: I'd suggest you batch and queue.

Comment: Show the code of the fetch function, there will be optimisation possible there.

Comment: I suppose there is no urgency, ... I moved on.

Comment: (Trincot timed out.)

Comment: what i mean is something similar like this keywordshitter dot com. it can process the function for long time without reload the page and no timeout.